# Select rows from dataframe by group by and select max in given column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set structured as follow. This a sample so please imagine a dataframe which contain many sequences. Few things to precise:
`time` are in descending order.
`created_at` is also in descending order.
Both `time` and `created_at` reset when a new `source` OR `currency` comes up.

```
index  time          app_v   last     source   currency   created_at
1      2019-10-23    3       4488     gol      JPY        66
2      2019-10-23    29193   6687     gol      JPY        65
3      2019-10-22    3       4587     gol      JPY        64
4      2019-10-20    3       5687     gol      JPY        63
5      2019-10-19    3       34787    gol      JPY        62
6      2019-10-18    3       11789    gol      JPY        61
...
```

The expected output is the latest `last` in terms of `time` grouped by `source` `currency` and `app_v`. For this sample, we have 2 rows corresponding:

```
index  time          app_v   last     source   currency   created_at
1      2019-10-23    3       4488     gol      JPY        66
2      2019-10-23    29193   6687     gol      JPY        65
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `last` which computes the last values for each group and use `iloc` to get the row values:

```
df.groupby(["source", "currency", "app_v"]).last().iloc[-1]
```

You can access the index group values using the name attribute like:
`df.get_group(df.groupby('a').last().iloc[-1].name)`

Comment: I quick fixed with the following `ext_bal = ext_bal.loc[ext_bal['time'] == ext_bal['time'].max()]` , `ext_bal` being the dataframe name. But I would like to be able to select the last n days with the same method. Not sure how to do that.

Comment: You can use my method only, and `df.groupby(["source", "currency", "app_v"]).last().iloc[-n]` pass `n` as the number of days